# ODT Microsoft errors

Tags: ms-office

So I've been downloading office 2019 through the microsoft page, which tells me I should download it with the ODT by using elevated command prompt with a configuration.xml file and a command in cmd

setup /download configuration.xml

now my question is this. why does it not download or if it downloads I get an error
the code I used eventually in the config is:

```
<Configuration>             
      <Add              
           SourcePath=""                
       OfficeClientEdition="64"             
       Channel="PerpetualVL2019"            
       AllowCdnFallback="True">         
          <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume"  PIDKEY="#####-#####-#####-#####-#####" >             
             <Language ID="nl-nl" />                
          </Product>                

      </Add>                
      <RemoveMSI All="True" />              
      <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />                
</Configuration>
```

and the code I used in cmd was setup /configure configuration.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This actually worked for me. You will need to change the path to where you are trying to download the software to and change the version from 64 to 32 if that is what you are looking for. Also change the Product ID to the version or product you are trying to download. You need to save it as configuration.xml otherwise it will not work (from my experience). Once this is done go into cmd (as admin) and go into the folder where the ODT was extracted to. Once you are there run the setup /download configuration.xml

You may want to check your product key to make sure you are installing the correct version for your product key.

In addition please note that Office 2019 is solely for Windows 10 and it will not work with Windows 7/8/8.1 or any previous versions.

```
   <Configuration>
        <Add 
            SourcePath="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Office2019"
            OfficeClientEdition="64" 
            Channel="PerpetualVL2019"
            AllowCdnFallback="True">
        <Product ID="Standard2019Volume"  PIDKEY="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" >
         <Language ID="en-us" />
        </Product>

        </Add>
       <RemoveMSI All="True" />
       <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />  
   </Configuration>
```